# Why can't I pickle <class '__main__.Person'>?

Tags: python, pickle

Why can't I pickle my "people" array? I'm taking user input adding it to an object, then appending that object to the "people" array.

```
import pickle

people = []

while True:
    class Person():
        def __init__(self, name, fav_color):
            self.name = name
            self.fav_color = fav_color

    name = input('Enter name: ')
    fav_color = input('Enter fav_color: ')

    new_object = Person(name, fav_color)

    people.append(new_object)

    op = input('Have another one? :')
    
    if op != 'Y' and op != 'y':
        with open('test.pickle', 'ab+') as f:
            pickle.dump(people, f)
        break
```

When I run this code I receive an error:

```
_pickle.PicklingError: Can't pickle <class '__main__.Person'>: it's not the same object as __main__.Person
```

I can print the array so I know my array is populating. Is there a way to cast <class 'main.Person'> as main.Person?

Comment: Umm.... is your `class Person` definition actually inside the `while True`?

Comment: You are redefining the class on every iteration of the `while True:` loop.  There's no way to reference the definition that created any particular object, because that version of the class no longer exists.  (The fact that all the versions of the class are identical is unknown to Python.)  Simply move the definition out of the loop.